# Vim get correct behavior for `gq` command inside a python doc string

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following documentation line in a python script.

```
def cdf():
    """
    Each line in the printed output will contain a fraction and a number, such that
    the given fraction of all numbers in the log file have values less than or
    equal to the given number.
    """
```

If I highlight the string contents and use the command `gq`, vim will make sure each line is only 80 characters long, but it will also tend to push the second and third line towards the left margin, which is undesirable. Is there a way to make `gq` reformat to ensure 80 character width without pushing the second two lines to the left?

Comment: For me, there's no pushing left. My `formatoptions` are `cqro`. What are yours?

Comment: @Amadan, I tried to match yours, but it does not appear to fix the problem. I think it must be something else.

Comment: Yeah, probably. But it's good to eliminate. Is your `autoindent` on? How about `paste`?

Comment: Bang! `autoindent` it was.